# Non-consistent user login fail on integrated security

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm experiencing that every now and then when I'm starting my .NET MVC application an SqlException is thrown

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Cannot open database "Foobar" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'CompanyDomain\StefanBols'
```

I'm using this connection string

```
Server=.\sqlexpress;initial catalog=Foobar;Integrated Security=true
```

Please note the Integrated Security flag is set and that this exception is thrown periodically – and not every time!
I must often restart my computer after an occurrence. Then the problem is gone for a while (2+ days).

I don't have any other applications running that uses the database either.
I've searched for this specific problem but don't seem to find any relevant solutions.

I think it is important to mention that my user account on the computer is in a user domain setup.
I'm part of a 7 man development team who doesn't experience the same issues – but uses the exact environment.

Versions:

> Application .NET framework 4.7.2
>
> MSSQL Server 13.0.4001
>
> Windows 10 Enterprise

Comment: `ALTER LOGIN [CompanyDomain\StefanBols] WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE = [master]`

Comment: Where master is the database I want my application to connect to?

Comment: No, the command as is. It seems sometimes your `Foobar` is not accessible that's why you get the error. Having master db as default you will be able to connect to your server if it's running but `Foobar` is offline or something.

Comment: Alright. I'll try to do that the next time the error occurs. Hang tight - and thank you :-)

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't fix it Denis

Comment: Hi,@Stefan, do you get another error after changing the login's default database to master?

Comment: Anyway check that your db is not auto closing `select DATABASEPROPERTYEX('Foobar', 'IsAutoClose')`.

Comment: select DATABASEPROPERTYEX('Foobar', 'IsAutoClose') - where Foobar is the database name, right?

This returns '1'. - So true?

Comment: Also; I didn't got another error after changing the login's default database to master - I just got the same error

Comment: So, just to spam the comments section - I've tried to set AutoClose to false in the database options. Let's see how this goes.

Comment: Hi, @Stefan, I was going to suggest you that option, I believe it would help.

Comment: @Denis the solution worked - I haven't seen the problem in over a week. Thank you! Please submit it as an answer :-)